# SQL query to compare two rows within the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have `pizza` table

| pizza_id | toppings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10 |
| 2 | 4,6,7,9,11,12 |

I would like to know toppings with each pizza_id in common. Most used toppings in both the pizza_id..., expected answer as below table

```
Pizza_id    toppings
1             4,6
2             4,6
```

I have tried using JOINS but couldn't satisfy the condition.
Could anyone please give me hint.
Thank you

Comment: You are not respecting 1NF: each table cell must contain a single value.  If you put more values inside a single cell you cannot make operation on it.

Comment: @shailaja What is DataType of coulmn toppings ?

Comment: normalise your data - search for mysql split string.  'most used toppings '- is pretty meaningless - do you mean toppings in common also if pizaa 3  only had topping 4 what would the output look like.

Comment: If you want to solve your task w/o changing the structure then you must parse each CSV to separate values, aggregate then select the values with COUNT=2.

Comment: @Tushar , it is text datatype

Comment: I totally agree with the others. Your database design is inappropriate and you should change it. If you can not change it for some reason, then use a recursive query to generate the normalized table from the original table. Then work with this. And yes, it is still not clear what you want precisely. It seems you want the toppings two pizzas have in common. So you want a query for two particular pizza IDs? Or d you want to compare each pizza with each other pizza? Add this information to your request.

Comment: yes I would like to know  toppings of two pizzas have in common. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Okay. Will you change the data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your db is not respecting 1NF:each table cell must contain a single value. The best way to do so is having `pizza_table` and `topping_table` with a N-to-N relationship. In this way there is a table containing the `pizza_id` related with **EVERY** topping it have.

Pizza table is formed as:

| pizza_id | pizza_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Margherita |
| 2 | Capricciosa |

Topping table is formed as:

| topping_id | topping_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pomodoro |
| 2 | Mozzarella |

And N-to-N table will be:

| pizza_id | topping_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

In this table you can make all operation you need to get your data.

Comment: This is right, but it would be nice to also show how this helps solve the issue at hand (select from the new table, group by topping_id, order by count(pizza_id) desc).

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by everyone, you should not be storing comma separated values in a single cell like that.

But, to answer your question, assuming you are looking for the intersection of the toppings CSV for all pizzas, and you have a toppings table with (topping_id, name), you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    p1.pizza_id AS p1_id,
    p2.pizza_id AS p2_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.topping_id) AS toppings,
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM pizzas p1
JOIN toppings t
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t.topping_id, REPLACE(p1.toppings, ', ', ','))
JOIN pizzas p2
    ON p1.pizza_id < p2.pizza_id
    AND FIND_IN_SET(t.topping_id, REPLACE(p2.toppings, ', ', ','))
GROUP BY p1.pizza_id, p2.pizza_id
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Given these pizzas:

| pizza_id | toppings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 |
| 2 | 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12 |
| 3 | 1, 6 |

The above query will return:

| p1_id | p2_id | toppings | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4,6 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1,6 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 1 |

This is insanely inefficient and would be much better served by the junction table suggested by ElNicho.

If you switch to using a junction (N-to-N) table like `pizzas_toppings (pizza_id, topping_id)`, the query becomes:

```
SELECT
    p1.pizza_id AS p1_id,
    p2.pizza_id AS p2_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p1.topping_id) AS toppings,
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM pizzas_toppings p1
JOIN pizzas_toppings p2
    ON p1.pizza_id < p2.pizza_id
    AND p1.topping_id = p2.topping_id
GROUP BY p1.pizza_id, p2.pizza_id
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Make sure your junction table is indexed in both directions:

```
CREATE TABLE `pizzas_toppings` (
    pizza_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    topping_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pizza_id, topping_id),
    INDEX (topping_id, pizza_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pizza_id) REFERENCES pizzas (pizza_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (topping_id) REFERENCES toppings (topping_id)
);
```