# SQL - How to parse out data with multiply values in single column with separated pipe delimiter

Tags: sql, denodo

I need a way to parse out data that contains multiply values in the same column. The values are separated by pipe delimiters.

Any help on how to achieve this in SQL would be great.

Current Table:

'''
[image]

Expected outcome needed:

'''
[image]

Comment: You are not respecting 1NF *"Each table cell must contain a single value"*. This is the first rule on Database Normalization. Check this [1NF Wikypedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75580192/9961286)

Comment: yep I understand the 1NF rule but I have a dataset that contains pipe delimiters in more than 1 column so i need to see if there is a way to normalize it

Comment: You have to create a table that contains all ```Interests``` data. This new table will have a N-to-N relationship with person table

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
If using a very old version of SQL you can write a UDF to do it - examples [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/641522/How-to-split-a-string-in-sql-server-2008-using-sto)